# How to use value from outside switch case?

Tags: android

I'm new in android studio and have a question. According to my code how I can use `ii` and `i`. I want to add them together and display in tv3 but always is 0. I know I should do something before `TextView` tv3 but I'm not professional.

```
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioGroup gr1,gr2;

Button driver;

int i,ii,iii;

TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gr1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.g1);
    gr2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.g2);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    driver=(Button) findViewById(R.id.driver);

    gr1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) 
{
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.r1:
                    i=1;
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    break;
                case R.id.r2:
                    i=1-1;
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    break;
            }


        }
    });
    gr2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) 
{
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.r3:
                    ii=1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                    break;
                case R.id.r4:
                    ii=1-1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));;
                    break;
            }

        }
    });


    tv3.setText(String.valueOf(iii));

    driver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (iii==2){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Complete", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "InComplete", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}


}
```

Comment: In `case R.id.r2` you're setting `i` equal to the number 1 minus the number 1, which is zero. You also never actually set `iii` equal to anything. I recommend you use more descriptive variable names..

Comment: you mean, you want `tv3` to show the value of `iii` (the sum of i and ii) after performing a click on `gr1` or `gr2`?

Comment: Yes Sir..... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `tv3.setText(String.valueOf(iii));` after the switch case code block.

If any time switch case execute then tv3 will show new value of iii. If want to add i and ii then just add them before setText()

```
gr2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.r3:
                    ii = 1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                    break;
                case R.id.r4:
                    ii = 1 - 1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                    break;
            }
            // add value
            iii = i + ii;
            tv3.setText(String.valueOf(iii));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Touhid for your complete answer. Is there any way to show "iii" without clicking on button?

Comment: In which situation you want to show iii? As, after clicking a button, value of iii will changed. So when value of iii is changed you need to show that.

Comment: I know, but I would like it to be changed without clicking on any items such button etc.

Answer (score 0):

First time when your activity is created the iii will be always 0 and only when you press the operation occur

**The value of iii is still zero even after you click radio button because you are not using addition anywhere**

```
gr1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) 
 {
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.r1:
                    i=1;
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    break;
                case R.id.r2:
                    i=1-1;
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    break;
            }
       iii = i+ii;
       tv3.setText(String.valueOf(iii));//here you can check whether iii is zero if 0 don't set otherwise set text

        }
    });

gr2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) 
{
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.r3:
                    ii=1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                    break;
                case R.id.r4:
                    ii=1-1;
                    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(ii));;
                    break;
            }
       iii = i+ii;
       tv3.setText(String.valueOf(iii));


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear friend for your answer. I appreciate it.